# Is it possible to implement custom intents in Google Smart Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-smart-home

I successfully created a basic application which turns the lights in a certain room on or off. This uses the built-in intent *'turn everything in living room on/off'*.

Is it possible to implement custom intents? Let's say I want to implement the intent *'put the lights in party mode'*, an intent which is not covered by the built-in intents. How can I do this? Can I route Google Smart Home services to Dialogflow intents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom intents as a concept are not supported in the [smart home integration](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome) for the Google Assistant. However, if you want to have specific feature sets like "party mode", you can create a ["SCENE"](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/scene) device in your `SYNC` response that has the [Scene](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/scene) trait. When the user says something like "activate party mode", your cloud integration will get an `EXECUTE` intent for that scene, which you can handle in any way.

Comment: Thanks. My question was mostly generic, but I will experiment with the `Scene` trait for sure.